# Get File Path of File Displayed in WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

Currently, if a WKWebview is given a url that points to a document (i.e. a PDF), it will display it. However, there is no way for one to use `UIDocumentInteractionController` with this document as the url is not a local one (i.e. http://dropbox.com/some/file.pdf) and `UIDocumentInteractionController` can only be pointed to a local file.

I have tried looking through the documentation for WKWebView and have not been able to find a way to determine where the docuemnt being previewed in WKWebView is being stored.

If anyone has managed to access the file before, do let me know.

Comment: Maybe add a method in javascript and return to the native code through message handler? https://kinderas.com/technology/2014/6/15/wkwebview-and-javascript-in-ios-8-using-swift